# Error when archiving iOS project regarding symbolic links

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I am receiving the following error when archiving an iOS project in Xcode:

```
SetOwnerAndGroup "james:staff" "/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_Name_Here-flplczeuioixfhgepbxgwsbmggyv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App_Name_Here/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/../BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos/libRestKitNetwork.a"
cd "/Users/james/Documents/iPhone SDK Projects/App_Name_Here/RestKit"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" /usr/sbin/chown -RH "james:staff" "/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_Name_Here-flplczeuioixfhgepbxgwsbmggyv/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App_Name_Here/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/../BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos/libRestKitNetwork.a"

chown: libRestKitNetwork.a: Too many levels of symbolic links
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure if this plays into it, but I recently updated to Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion to build for iOS 6. What is causing this? If it is an infinite loop of symbolic links, is it in an Xcode generated directory? I have not created any symbolic links on my own.

Thank you immensely for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by cleaning out RestKit from the project and updating it to the latest version. I wish I had more details about what solved it specifically, but that is what ended up happening.

Comment: Did you find out some more information? I have the same situation right now and if need to update RestKit this is a timeplan breaking thing!